# Xamarin.Forms Shared Project Web Service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, shared-project

How can i add web service reference to shared or portable project to add it automatically on another projects (Android, IOS, Windows Phone) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add web service references in Android and IOS project, Then help of Dependency services you can consume data in Portable class.
Here is good explanation to- [WebService consume](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/asmx/)